# Get ID of entity within array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have an entity which stores an array of the same entity, this is called Review[], it stores:

ID, review

Now within my controller, I loop through an array of ratings which stores:

ID, reviewID

How do I grab the the Review object from the Review array using the reviewID from the ratings?

This is what I've done so far:

```
foreach($ratings as $rating)
{
   // Grab the review from the id stored in rating
   $review = $reviews->findById ??
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seems like you solver your "subqueries" problem from another question, and now you try something else with this one... It would be good for you to start posting more code... We can't help you much as it's... I will ask here again, but post your entity files... We don't know how you made the relationship... By default, just getting the parent should be enough (`$rating->getReview()`), that is if entities relationship was done right...

Comment: @Preciel The entities are done right, since their are OneToMany/ManyToOne relationships with both of them, they're linked perfectly. I'm just trying to figure the most efficient way of this foreach loop

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that we don't know how you linked them... Which variable name you used in the parent and child... Still, you should have your answer in my first comment, Though, not sure that it's exactly `$ratings->getReview()` as I don't know how is named the function in your entity... If you don't want to disclose your code, invest some time in renaming...

Answer (score 1):

I see the point that @Nietvoordekat is trying to make.

Try this:

```
foreach($ratings as $key => $value){
   if ($key == 'reviewID'){
      $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Review');
      $review = $repo->findOneBy( array( 'id' => $value ) );
   }
}
```

For the above, I'm not sure if you Entity is called `Review` or if the Review entity `Id` is called `id`. So you may need to change that. But I think this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use a foreach loop as you've done, but you can also use a foreach loop as such:

```
foreach($ratings as $id->$rating) {
    //...
}
```

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: I get "Undefined variable rating"

Comment: Because he shows `$id->$rating`. I think he intended `$id->rating`.